# Spring Mongodb search string inside binary data

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am storing document(text,pdf,csv,doc,docx etc) in mongodb using spring rest.Documents are getting stored as binary data.
Now i want to search documents based on contents inside it.
For e.g. if user searches for string "office", he should see list of documents that contains string "office".
How can i query mongodb for data contains in binary data?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to define a text index over your binary files. I don't know if it would work, but even if it does, such an index would match any words that are part of the *file format* rather than user content which is generally undesirable.

If I was implementing your requirements I would use a transformer from all of the binary documents to plain text (e.g. [pandoc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc)), thus obtaining the user content of each of the documents, then insert that content into a field which has a text index over it, then query on that field.